# Is there any segulah associated with the coins used in a Pidyon Haben?

Tags: segulah, pidyon-haben

I was told that there is a segulah (for Shemirah, or something or other) associated with the coins used for a pidyon haben, and that some even make jewelry out of it in order to keep the coin with them at all times. I have not been able to find a source for this (and most people I have asked about it have not heard of it).

Has anyone heard of this? Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: Welcome @bob bobble. The coins are essentially paid to the Kohen by the father of the firstborn.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Thanks. I understand that, but don't see how it addresses my question...can you please explain?

Comment: In your question, who do you imagine keeps the coin with them at all times? I think it is unlikely the Kohen would do that.

Comment: Ah. I understand that the kohen has the coins at the end of the ceremony. What I was told is that the kohen will sometimes give [some of] the coins back to the father, and/or that they are sometimes sold for their segulah properties.